# How to identify and save the right "user" when we use Django (Existing proj) for authentication and FastAPI (new feature) for API's?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, fastapi

Hello guys I have an existing Django project which has certain features and also has user data. For certain features, users use the API served through Django (also the authentication), but since there is a need for new feature which needs to be implemented through FastAPI,  I need to have the same users authenticate or (better to say) to be recognized by FastAPI (as the same user in Django) to save or retrieve an action corresponding to user in the db (through FastAPI).

How to achieve that? How do I store the user data, like `user_id` and `username` for each user safely? How to properly design the database table?

Please do let me know, how to start.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe authentication via Json web tokens will be enough for you?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I haven't worked with multiple frameworks before, so I am a bit confused on how I should save the data in db? like with user_id? how to validate the jwt token for each request? or is there another way? If you could tell more, it would be great.

Comment: How are you authenticating currently?

Comment: Using JWT tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've implemented your own `AbstractUser` sub-class named `DannyUser`, you then have a couple of choices:

- Embed all of the information needed into a new field (a `JSONField` subclass for example) -- not really recommended as this leaks random information into a housekeeping table and is ill-advised IMO.
- Design a new Model for each authentication service and tie it via a foreign key & reverse relationship to your `DannyUser` instances. Then you could use something like `my_danny_instance.fastapi_account.auth_token` where needed. This will also allow you to encrypt specific fields or use a secret management solution later on.

Simply normalize your data as far as it makes sense to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am having a custom user model and currently using JWT tokens for authentication. Do you mean to create a separate model to the the user's token details and validate for each request?

Comment: Either a separate model or even a simple field like `user_jwt_token` for each `User` model instance that needs to store it; adding a new model and linking with M2M FKs offers greater flexibility in the future, though

Comment: Oh..Thank you for the response, I will try that out.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a software architecture design problem, In your old login endpoint put every required data by the new FastAPI project in the JWT token payload(such as user_id, user_name and etc), sign it and give it to the user:

```
# using PyJWT
import jwt
user_token = jwt.encode(
     {"user_id": "1222", "user_name": "yosef", },
     "YOUR_SECRET_KEY",
     algorithm="HS256",
     headers={},
)
```

Afterwards in new FastAPI project endpoint, validate JWT token in request header with the key you have signed it in Django login endpoint:

```
# using PyJWT
import jwt

try:
    data = jwt.decode(JWT_STRING_VAR, "YOUR_SECRET_KEY", algorithms=["HS256"])
except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
    # reject
    ...
```

If the token is valid you accept the request and use the payload as confirmed data to do your usual endpoint functionality and if sign is not valid reject request.
This way you are not required to change your old endpoints at all.
*note: instead of PyJWT you can use SimpleJWT or any other package for Django and a suitable JWT package for FastAPI
**note: this scenario may go crazy complex when your JWT payload may get changed before the JWT expires, like when user_name changes but you can not change that in JWT and user can use it in your other service with old data, there are more solutions on this, like removing the properties that may change from payload and get them directly from database, meaning you query Django populated table from FastAPI, you can achieve this by import dynamic tables in SQLAlchemy
***note: system design schema image
[image]

Comment: Oh..great, the last section seems promising even though its a bit complex, and looks a bit expensive too. Let me try that.

Thank you